# Does PhoneGap Support HTTPS ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, cordova

I have an application where the html/javascript code executes fine in a standalone browser safari, but when the ajax calls are executed in PhoneGap, they all fail with the Network Error 101.

I am requesting XML documents

Comment: AFAIK PhoneGap can support HTTPS requests but many have come across problems with self-signed certificates. Is it iPhone or Android you're running with PhoneGap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

BUT, it does not gracefully handle certificate errors with the HTTPS protocol. I ended up writing my own code to establish the initial connection with the server and ignore the cert errors

here is the code
http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1012434483/phonegap-and-iphone-development

Comment: Does this still exist? It 404's

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap does support HTTPS ajax requests, but like Aaron mention it does not gracefully handle certificate errors. In my case, we have valid certs in our production environment; but for our dev environment we overrode one of the NSUrl methods:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest (IgnoreSSL)

+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

This has been tested with phonegap 1.7(and 1.9) and it worked well. You can put this code in your MainViewController.m.

Note that I recommend this code only for development environment. This most likely will not be accepted by the app store; since we are overriding a private api. Just use valid certs in production.

Comment: It don't work with Cordova 1.5 and Xcode 4 (the allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost method is never called)

Comment: I am still using this code in my environment just fine(note that I am running Cordove 1.9 now). So there is a chance this is not working with Cordova 1.5; but from quickly glancing over apple discussion boards; this has been supported for quite some time. Just make sure you put it above your "@implementation MainViewController".