# "HTTPS" request on windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

My Question is similar to this question [Does PhoneGap Support HTTPS ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560881/does-phonegap-support-https-ajax-requests) . I am able to use  ***"allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:"*** in iOS for accessing the "https" service. Is there any way to access the "https" in windows phone 8. I am using "Sencha touch with Cordova" for windows phone package.

Comment: I have the same problem... is there any way to access HTTPS service in WP8? I use `allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost` in iOS and `onReceivedSslError` in Android...